# Javafx: Change scene in setOnAction

Tags: javafx, stage, scene

I'm building a JavaFX application with multiple Scenes. I have a problem with scope of variable when changing scenes within setOnAction event. This is my code:

```
Stage myStage;

public Scene logInScene(){
   ... all the buttons / textFields

   createAccountButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        public void handle(ActionEvent t){
              **this.getStage().allScene(createAccountPane1);**
        }
   }
}

public Stage getStage(){
      return this.myStage;
}

public void allScene(Pane p){
      this.myStage.setScene(p);
}
```

I'm getting an error within the setOnAction function. "Cannot Find Symbol" getStage(). I know this must be a scope problem and it doesn't recognize any variables / functions outside of that scope. How do I make it so that I can change within? I've tried passing through the variable but that will just make my code messy and I wish there was a simpler way. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works as long as you keep consistency:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application{
    private Stage stage;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        stage = primaryStage;
        Scene scene = logInScene();
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public Scene logInScene(){
        Pane root = new Pane();
        Button createAccountButton = new Button("create account");
        createAccountButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            public void handle(ActionEvent t){
                  stage.setScene(CreateAccountScene());
            }
       });
        root.getChildren().add(createAccountButton);
        return new Scene(root);
    }
    protected Scene CreateAccountScene() {
        VBox root = new VBox();
        Label userLabel = new Label("Insert the username:");
        final TextField userField = new TextField();
        Button createAccountButton = new Button("create account");
        createAccountButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            public void handle(ActionEvent t){
                  System.out.println("Account for user " + userField.getText() + " was created succesfully");
            }
       });
        root.getChildren().addAll(userLabel,userField,createAccountButton);
        return new Scene(root);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This question has already been solved, but I think it's worth clarifying that your line fails because the `this` keyword refers to the anonymous EventHandler you are implementing. In Java, you reference the outer class instance with `OuterClass.this`. So `OuterClass.this.getStage().allScene(createAccountPane1);` will work.

If you are looking for a prettier solution, some coders like to define a local variable that points to the outer class instance:

```
final OuterClass self = this;
createAccountButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        public void handle(ActionEvent t){
              self.getStage().allScene(createAccountPane1);
        }
}
```